# Não consigo utilizar o método FirstOrDefault em um tipo IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Não estou conseguindo utilizar o método FirstOrDefault com o selenium

```cs
public IWebElement RetornaRegistro(string titulo)
{
    var trs = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table tbody tr"));
    var alvo = trs.FirstOrDefault(tr => tr.Text.Contains(titulo));

    if (alvo == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Erro ao buscar a tarefa cadastrada.");
    }

    return alvo;
}
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Mark7   C:\Users\rodrigo.rebes\source\repos\Mark7\Mark7\Pages\TaskPage.cs   33  Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso se dá porque você está usando o `FindElement()` na atribuição da variável trs, onde o mesmo apenas retorna um único elemento, levando em consideração que o `FirstOrDefault()` é usado para `Enumerables`.

`FindElement()`:

> Procura o primeiro elemento IWebElement usando o método passado.

`FindElements()`:

> Uma coleção ReadOnlyCollection de todos *WebElements* que combinam com os critérios atuais ou então uma lista vazia caso não combine.

Então troque o `FindElement()` por `FintElements()`:

```js
var trs = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table tbody tr"));
```

Mais informações:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm